# How to determine Kotlin version for old Gradle version?

Tags: kotlin, gradle, kotlin-gradle-plugin

I have an existing project using Gradle 5.6.3, which is currently building Java-only Android. I'd like to add a library in Kotlin.

I had IntelliJ generate a library module, which gave me the following configuration:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
}
```

and in my parent project

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.30'
    }
}
```

However, when I run this, it fails, saying `The current Gradle version 5.6.3 is not compatible with the Kotlin Gradle plugin. Please use Gradle 6.1.1 or newer, or the previous version of the Kotlin plugin.`

Because of reasons, upgrading Gradle is not an option for the project right now. So I want to satisfy Gradle by using "the previous version".

I already looked at the [compatibility matrix](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/compatibility.html), but that only says that `Gradle is tested with Kotlin 1.3.72 through 1.6.0.`, which isn't helpful.

So, which version of the `kotlin-gradle-plugin` do I need if I want to stay on Gradle 5.6.3?

Comment: Figured out that it works with Kotlin 1.4.20. Still, it'd be great if Gradle could document these dependencies somewhere.